# How to use with torch.cuda.device() conditionally

Tags: pytorch

I have some code encapsulated in a:

```
with torch.cuda.device(self.device):
    # do a bunch of stuff
```

And in my `__init__` I have:

```
self.device = torch.device('cuda:0') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')
```

But I'm a little confused about how to deal with a situation where the device is cpu. Because `torch.cuda.device` is already explicitly for `cuda`. Should I just write a decorator for the function? Seems a bit overkill

Comment: According to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.device). "device (*torch.device* or *int*) – device index to select. **It’s a no-op if this argument is a negative integer or `None`**." So probably something like `with torch.cuda.device(self.device if self.device.type != 'cuda' else None):` would work? Difficult to say without explicit example of use case.

Comment: Nice (feel free to add as answer and I will accept)! And as a follow up question, rather than actively hunting down everywhere I need to use this context block, is there a way of setting it globally?

Comment: I haven't really played much with this functionality since I usually explicitly move my tensors and model parameters to specific devices (e.g. `model.to('cuda:1')` or `t = torch.tensor([1,2,3]).to('cuda:1')`). But it seems there's a [`torch.cuda.set_device`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.set_device) function which selects a device, potentially a global solution.

Comment: Ah right! For some reason I thought I tested that and it didn't work. But all done now. Thankyou

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`torch.cuda.device`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/cuda.html#torch.cuda.device)

> device (torch.device or int) – device index to select. **It’s a no-op if this argument is a negative integer or `None`**.

Based on that we could use something like

```
with torch.cuda.device(self.device if self.device.type == 'cuda' else None):
    # do a bunch of stuff
```

which would simply be a no-op when `self.device` isn't a CUDA device.